# Fabric : pipe task's output as another task input

Tags: python, fabric

I'd like to chain two tasks :

- the first one creates an archive (`create_archive`) with an arbitrary name
- the second one uploads an archive to a FTP server (`upload_archive`)

I'd like to invoke them like this : `fab create_archive upload_archive`

Is there a way/syntax to automatically pass the `create_archive`'s output to the `upload_archive`'s output like the bash `|` character does ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like it. I don't see any mentions in the fabric docs either at http://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.10/.

The closest thing I can think of is managing state with an outside variable, say something attached to `env` or a global variable in the module.

i.e.:

```
from fabric.api import run, env, task

@task
def setup():
    env.hosts = ['localhost']

env.counter = 1
env.lines = ""

@task
def task1():
    env.counter += 1
    result = run("seq {}".format(env.counter))
    env.lines += "#task1\n{}".format(result)


@task
def task2():
    env.counter += 1
    result = run("seq {}".format(env.counter))
    env.lines += "#task2\n{}".format(result)

@task
def task3():
    print repr(env.lines)

# fab setup task1 task2 task3
```

Then in the shell:

```
$ fab setup task1 task2
```